# Bundler could not find compatible versions - without contradictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to `bundle update` a couple of gems and get back (amongst others) the following error from bundler (version 1.16.2):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.0.13) was resolved to 4.0.13, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.0.13) was resolved to 4.0.13, which depends on
        activemodel (= 4.0.13)

    draper (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0)

    simple_form (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
```

I cannot see any **contradictions** in these requirements at all!

Why doesn't Bundler just use `activemodel` version  `4.0.13`?

Comment: Sounds like a known `bundler` issue: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6454